# Why are there so many subway station signs between Yau Ma Tei station and Mong Kok station on Google Maps?

Tags: public-transport, hong-kong, maps

Looking at the map between [Yau Ma Tei station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yau_Ma_Tei_station) and [Mong Kok station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mong_Kok_station) on Google Maps, https://www.google.com/maps/place/Yau+Ma+Tei+Fruit+Market/@22.3161599,114.1698839,19z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x4d3b0f2049180597!8m2!3d22.3120217!4d114.1687407 ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20191019204437/http://web.archive.org/screenshot/https://www.google.com/maps/place/Yau+Ma+Tei+Fruit+Market/%4022.3161599,114.1698839,19z/data%3D!4m5!3m4!1s0x0%3A0x4d3b0f2049180597!8m2!3d22.3120217!4d114.1687407)), I see many subway station signs at a specific location:

[image: mutual sites]

Why are there so many subway station signs between Yau Ma Tei Fruit station and Mong Kok Station on Google Maps? Are they truly subway station exits?

Typically subway station signs in Hong Kong have some exit letters/numbers, e.g.: [image]

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These are almost certainly errors on the Google Maps map.  These are NOT subway exits, or anything else that would be worthy of showing such a marker.

Mong Kok station does have multiple entrances, however as you've said these are all numbered, and signs within the station use these numbers to direct you to the best exit for a specific location.

There is also an exit which feeds underground into the Langham Place shopping centre, so it could be argued that all entrances to Langham Place are also entrances to the subway - however the icons you've pointed out are nowhere near Langham Place.

Yau Ma Tei is a smaller station, with fewer entrances - but again none of those are anywhere near the area you've highlighted.

Comment: Not worthy of answer of its own, though I can confirm the southernmost exits of Mong Kok station (E1/2) is at Nelson St/Nathan Rd, two blocks north of the markers shown in the OP's question, and the northernmost exit of Yau Ma Tei station (A) is at Pitt St/Nathan Rd, two blocks south of the markers shown in the OP's question. There are no plans to create new exits in these stations in the near future.